# Is there a function in numpy to compare arrays of multiple dimensions similar to numpy.where function?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get slices of data (based on the array values) for very big arrays (len>1000000). See next python code for an example to what I'm trying to do in pure python:

```py
vector=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
start=[1,4,9]  # start and end lists have the same length
end=[2,7,9]
output=[[]]*len(start)
for indx1 in range(len(start)):
    temp=[]
    for indx2 in range(len(vector)):
        if ( (vector[indx2]>=start[indx1]) and (vector[indx2]<=end[indx1]) ):
            temp.append(vector[indx2])
        output[indx1]=temp
print output
```

vector list has normally 25E+6 elements while start and end lists have like 1E6 elements, that's why doing this on pure python is very slow.

Do you know a why to use numpy to avoid for loops to solve this problem?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Will `vector` be sorted?  If not, will it hurt to sort it, or do you need to keep the original order?

Comment: Will the intervals defined by `start` and `end` be sorted and non-overlapping?

Comment: The order of vector must be maintained.

Comment: And the intervals defined by start and end cannot be sorted and they can overlap

Comment: So the order of the output values matters, and values that are contained in multiple intervals should be contained in multiple output lists?

Comment: Yes, the order of output matters and values contained in multiple intervals should be contained in multiple output lists

Comment: vector=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: vector=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; start=[1,4,9]; end=[5,6,9] --> output=[[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6],[9]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If vector is sorted this should be quite fast:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip

vector = np.array([2.0, 2.24, 3.1, 4.768, 16.8, 16.9,23.5,24.0])
start = np.array([3.0,4.5,6.5,15.2])
end = np.array([7.3,16.2,17.7,25.8])
start_i = vector.searchsorted(start, 'left')
end_i = vector.searchsorted(end, 'right')
output = [vector[s:e] for s, e in izip(start_i, end_i)]
print output
[array([ 3.1  ,  4.768]), array([ 4.768]), array([ 16.8,  16.9]), array([ 16.8,  16.9,  23.5,  24. ])]
```

You can also so something similar in pure python, it's not quite as fast but it doesn't require numpy:

```
from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right
from itertools import izip

vector = [2.0, 2.24, 3.1, 4.768, 16.8, 16.9,23.5,24.0]
start = [3.0,4.5,6.5,15.2]
end = [7.3,16.2,17.7,25.8]
se = izip(start, end)
output = [vector[bisect_left(vector, s):bisect_right(vector, e)] for s, e in se]
print output
[[3.1, 4.768], [4.768], [16.8, 16.9], [16.8, 16.9, 23.5, 24.0]]
```

Comment: No, vector list should not be repeated. Vector is: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and output should be: [[1,2],[4,5,6,7],[9]] when start is [1,4,9] and end is [2,7,9].

Comment: This is a more realistic example: In case vector is [2.0, 2.24, 3.1, 4.768, 16.8, 16.9,23.5,24.0], start is [3.0,4.5,6.5,15.2] and end is [7.3,16.2,17.7,25.8]; output must be [[2.0,2.24,3.1,4.768],[4.768],[16.8,16.9],[16.8,24.0]].

Comment: Notice that the code you gave us doesn't produce the output you gave, it produces: `[[3.1, 4.768], [4.768], [16.8, 16.9], [16.8, 16.9, 23.5, 24.0]]` Also in your more realistic example vector is sorted. This makes a big difference, can we assume that vector will always be sorted. That's what I was trying to get at with this question. If you make what you need more clear we can try to write a good answer.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks for the clarification. Vector will always be sorted.

Comment: Thanks Bago, it works perfectly and it's really fast. I appreciate the support. -Regards-

Comment: @Memolo: If this answers your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark on the left.  If you had answered my first comment (asking if vector is sorted), you would have got this answer immediately.